# Using DynamicActivityProperty as OutArgument in ActivityBuilder

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Greetings,

I'm trying to create a workflow using a ActivityBuilder, and then get the XAML.
This flow use a custom activity (WaitForInput) to handle bookmarks. This class inherits from NativeActivity.

I'm having a hard time finding a way to set 'Result' property of my WaitForInput activity, which expects a OutArgument.

Creating this same workflow by the VS designer, I could associate the boolean property 'MyResult' InOutArgument called 'wrapper'. Like this : [Wrapper.MyResult]

I would do this by code, and according to my research, I have to use DynamicActivityProperty.
The problem is that I don't know how to use my DynamicActivityProperty as OutArgument in this case.

This is an simplified version of the code:

```
        var wrapper = new DynamicActivityProperty
                    {
                        Name = "Wrapper",
                        Type = typeof(InOutArgument<CommunicationWrapper>),
                    };

        var activityBuilder = new ActivityBuilder();
        activityBuilder.Properties.Add(wrapper);

        var step1 = new FlowStep
        {
            //here's my problem
            Action = new WaitForInput<bool> { BookmarkName = "step1", Result = ??? }
        };

        var flow =  new Flowchart
        {
            StartNode = step1,
            Nodes = { step1 }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have founded a solution to my own problem

```
Result = new OutArgument<bool>(new VisualBasicReference<bool> 
                { ExpressionText = "Wrapper.MyResult" }); }
```